# Is there any way to store Observable variables in Room persistance table?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, android-room

I'm using Room library to save and retrieve data for my application. The model class *User* is having variables like - Observable name etc where Observable is RxJava class. But now gradle build is failing due to - **error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.**

So I'm looking how can we save Observable variable to table? 
I'm aware of type converters but unable to get how to do this. Like save String value from Observable to Database then convert it again to Observable when we get data from Database.

Any hints please?

Comment: why do you want to store Observable to database?

Comment: So that i can observe on changes in model class object retrieved from Room database. See I get User list from Room, And User object is having name variable which is observable e.g.
class User { Observable<String> name}
so that i will add obeserver on this variable itself.

Comment: Here's the way to observe model changed https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757

Answer (score 0):

You can do somthing like

```
@Entity(tableName = "my_table")
public class MyTable { 

    @ColumnInfo(name = "my_string_value")
    public String myStringValue;
}
```

Then create your DAO

```
@Dao
public class MyTableDao {

    @Query("select my_string_value from my_table limit 1 ") 
    Flowable<String> selectMyStringValue();

}


Flowable<String> flowable = myAppDataBase.getMyTableDao().selectMyStringValue();
```

I don't know why you want to save an Observable... but first of all you shouldn't .

To use the code from above you have to add the RxJava2 dependency because Flowable.